# Usable Lightweight Package Systems in PHP

Tags: php, plugins, installation

In **my toolkit** I'm looking to implement automated installation of add-ons. I would need to maintain dependencies as well as interact with centralized API, perform updates and more.

I suppose I might develop this myself, but if there is already a **lightweight** and flexible system I can build on, I'd rather do that. Please suggest if there is anything out there.

Answer (score 0):

Composer might be a good solution:

http://getcomposer.org/